# React Hook error when calling the Apollo useQuery()

Tags: react-hooks, apollo-client, react-context, react-apollo-hooks

i am getting the below error while i am trying to use the useQuery(). Plese let me know if you need additional details..

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
>   of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
>   reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See  for tips about how to debug and
>   fix this problem.

my code is as below...

**get-characters-action.js**

```
import React from "react";
import * as ACTION_TYPES from "./../constants/action-types";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export const getCharactersSuccess = (data) => {
    return {
        type:ACTION_TYPES.LOAD_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS,
        data
    }
}

export const getCharactersInProgress = () => {
    return {
        type:ACTION_TYPES.LOAD_CHARACTERS_INPROGRESS
    }
}

export const getCharactersError = (error) => {
    return {
        type:ACTION_TYPES.LOAD_CHARACTERS_ERROR,
        error
    }
}

const GET_CHARACTERS =gql`
{
    allPersons {
        name
        gender
        homeworld {
            name
        }
        species {
            name
            language
            classification
        }
    }
}`;

export const useGetCharacters= () => {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_CHARACTERS);

    if(loading) {
        getCharactersInProgress();
    }

    if(error) {
        getCharactersError(error);
    }

    if(data) {
        getCharactersSuccess(data);
    }
}
```

**context-state-config.js**

```
export const ContextState = (props) => {
    // const [stateReducer, dispatchReducer] = useReduceWithLogger(Reducer.AppLoadingReducer,Reducer.initialState);
    const [stateReducer, dispatchReducer] = useReducer(Reducer.MainReducer,Reducer.initialState);

    const handleDispatchAppLoadingInProgress = () => {
        dispatchReducer(GENERIC_ACTION.appLoadingInprogress());
    }

    const handleDispatchAppLoadingSuccess = () => {
        dispatchReducer(GENERIC_ACTION.appLoadingSuccess());
    }

    // const getCharacters = () => {
    //     dispatchReducer(GET_CHARACTERS_ACTION.useGetCharacters());
    // }

    const graphqlClient = new ApolloClient({
        uri: "https://swapi.graph.cool/"
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <ApolloProvider client={graphqlClient}>
                <Context.Provider
                    value={{
                        // reducer
                        isAppReady: stateReducer.isAppReady,
                        dispatchAppLoading: () => handleDispatchAppLoadingInProgress(),
                        dispatchAppLoaded: () => handleDispatchAppLoadingSuccess(),
                        // get character action
                        getCharacters: () => dispatchReducer(GET_CHARACTERS_ACTION.useGetCharacters())
                    }}
                >

                        {
                            props.children
                        }
                </Context.Provider>
            </ApolloProvider>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't invoke your `GET_CHARACTERS_ACTION.useGetCharacters()` inside another function it is like custom react hook that should be called only inside your functional react component.